# Visual C++ Windows Form prevent object from being deleted

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm beginner to Visual C++ Windows Forms and i have kind of huge problem (I can't find solution for a few days...)
Basically i have basic program form Online Templates. I added a few text boxes, labels, button and a class. Class is a BattleCard and it's supossed to "fight" using it's Defend()  function and using text box Text as their stats. The problem appears when i try to make this like turn based, so you need to click Start button every round... Everything is fine except the fact, that once i clicked button and all calculations are finished... Object and all stats are deleted. That means object will start with start HP etc. instead of one it just calculated. Do you have any ideas how to work around it or just make these objects "undeletable"?

BattleCard.h

```
#pragma once
ref class BattleCard
{
public:
    int Attack;
    int Defense;
    int HP;
    bool Exist = false;
    void Defend(int Attack, int Defense);
    BattleCard(int A, int D, int H);
};
```

BattleCard.cpp

```
#include "BattleCard.h"

BattleCard::BattleCard(int A, int D, int H)
{
    if (Exist == false) { Attack = A; Defense = D;  HP = H; Exist = true; }
}

void BattleCard::Defend(int Attack, int Defense)
{
    this->HP = (double)this->HP - (double)Attack*((double)1 - ((double)Defense / ((double)Defense + (double)50)));
}
```

MyForm.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "BattleCard.h"

namespace CppWinForm2 {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Panel^  panel2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label8;

    private: System::ComponentModel::IContainer^  components;




    protected:

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>


#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->panel1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->panel2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Panel());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->textBox4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textBox6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label8 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->panel1->SuspendLayout();
            this->panel2->SuspendLayout();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // textBox1
            // 
            this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 0);
            this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
            this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->textBox3);
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->textBox2);
            this->panel1->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
            this->panel1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(365, 202);
            this->panel1->Name = L"panel1";
            this->panel1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(206, 100);
            this->panel1->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // label3
            // 
            this->label3->AutoSize = true;
            this->label3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 81);
            this->label3->Name = L"label3";
            this->label3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 13);
            this->label3->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label3->Text = L"HP";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this->label2->AutoSize = true;
            this->label2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 45);
            this->label2->Name = L"label2";
            this->label2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(47, 13);
            this->label2->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label2->Text = L"Defense";
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this->label1->AutoSize = true;
            this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, 2);
            this->label1->Name = L"label1";
            this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 13);
            this->label1->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label1->Text = L"Attack";
            this->label1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::label1_Click);
            // 
            // textBox3
            // 
            this->textBox3->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 80);
            this->textBox3->Name = L"textBox3";
            this->textBox3->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox3->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox2
            // 
            this->textBox2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 40);
            this->textBox2->Name = L"textBox2";
            this->textBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox2->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->textBox4);
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->textBox5);
            this->panel2->Controls->Add(this->textBox6);
            this->panel2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(595, 202);
            this->panel2->Name = L"panel2";
            this->panel2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(206, 100);
            this->panel2->TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // label4
            // 
            this->label4->AutoSize = true;
            this->label4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 83);
            this->label4->Name = L"label4";
            this->label4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(22, 13);
            this->label4->TabIndex = 5;
            this->label4->Text = L"HP";
            // 
            // label5
            // 
            this->label5->AutoSize = true;
            this->label5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 45);
            this->label5->Name = L"label5";
            this->label5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(47, 13);
            this->label5->TabIndex = 4;
            this->label5->Text = L"Defense";
            // 
            // label6
            // 
            this->label6->AutoSize = true;
            this->label6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(3, 2);
            this->label6->Name = L"label6";
            this->label6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 13);
            this->label6->TabIndex = 3;
            this->label6->Text = L"Attack";
            // 
            // textBox4
            // 
            this->textBox4->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 80);
            this->textBox4->Name = L"textBox4";
            this->textBox4->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox4->TabIndex = 2;
            // 
            // textBox5
            // 
            this->textBox5->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 40);
            this->textBox5->Name = L"textBox5";
            this->textBox5->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox5->TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // textBox6
            // 
            this->textBox6->Location = System::Drawing::Point(106, 0);
            this->textBox6->Name = L"textBox6";
            this->textBox6->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 20);
            this->textBox6->TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(545, 326);
            this->button1->Name = L"button1";
            this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
            this->button1->TabIndex = 7;
            this->button1->Text = L"FIGHT!";
            this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button1_Click);
            // 
            // label7
            // 
            this->label7->AutoSize = true;
            this->label7->Location = System::Drawing::Point(543, 435);
            this->label7->Name = L"label7";
            this->label7->Size = System::Drawing::Size(28, 13);
            this->label7->TabIndex = 8;
            this->label7->Text = L"XXX";
            // 
            // label8
            // 
            this->label8->AutoSize = true;
            this->label8->Location = System::Drawing::Point(592, 435);
            this->label8->Name = L"label8";
            this->label8->Size = System::Drawing::Size(28, 13);
            this->label8->TabIndex = 9;
            this->label8->Text = L"XXX";
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(1280, 720);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label8);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->panel2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->panel1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->panel1->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->panel1->PerformLayout();
            this->panel2->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->panel2->PerformLayout();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();



        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void label1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

//      Battle_Card Card1(Int32::Parse(textBox1->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox2->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox3->Text));
//      Battle_Card Card2(Int32::Parse(textBox6->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox5->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox4->Text));

        BattleCard^ Card1 = gcnew BattleCard(Int32::Parse(textBox1->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox2->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox3->Text));
        BattleCard^ Card2 = gcnew BattleCard(Int32::Parse(textBox6->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox5->Text), Int32::Parse(textBox4->Text));

        label8->Text = System::Convert::ToString(Card2->HP);
        if (Card1->HP > 0 && Card2->HP > 0)
        {
            Card2->Defend(Card1->Attack, Card2->Defense);
        }

        label8->Text = System::Convert::ToString(Card2->HP);
        if (Card2->HP > 0 && Card1->HP > 0)
        {
            Card1->Defend(Card2->Attack, Card1->Defense);
        }
        label7->Text = System::Convert::ToString(Card1->HP);
    }
    }; //After MyForm.h is finished, all variables are deleted.
}
```

How to prevent them from being deleted? Do i need to put them in MyForm.cpp or something?

Comment: You're creating (`gcnew`) two new cards each time you click on the button. Make them class members instead of locals.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Make object class member? Well i have no idea what are you talking about...

Comment: Well, then I won't be able to help you much. Find a beginner-level book and start from there. Also, you probably shouldn't use C++/CLI at this point, as this language has a very specific purpose (binding C/C++ code with .NET code) and there are better solutions available for pretty much anything else.